# Want to allow user to to pick datetime using the django model and forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, datetimepicker

I have a Django model that records the DateTime of reservation. and I'm not able to create a date and time picker!

I have created a model and form which allows picking a date but not time.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Reservation(models.Model):
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ReserveDate = models.DateTimeField()
    Time = models.TimeField()
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Reservation
from datetime import datetime


class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'


class TimeInput(forms.TimeInput):
    input_type = 'time'


class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ['LastName', 'FirstName', 'ReserveDate', 'Time']
        widgets = {
           'ReserveDate':DateInput(),
           'Time':TimeInput(),
        }
```

**Reservation.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<style>
    .asteriskField {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2>
                    Contact
                </h2>
                <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Create" />

                </form>
            </div>  
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to see the date and time on the DateTime picker filed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Installation

- Run `pip install django-datetimepicker`
- Add `'datetimepicker'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

### Basic usage

Here is an example of how to use the widget.
Further examples can be found in the example project.

1. Assign the `DateTimePicker` to a `DateTimeField`, `DateField` or `TimeField`.

```py
from django import forms
from datetimepicker.widgets import DateTimePicker


class SampleForm(forms.Form):

datetime = forms.DateTimeField(
widget=DateTimePicker(),
)
```

This will render the following `html` code:

```html
<div class=" date input-group" id="datetimepicker_id_datetime">
<input class=" form-control" id="id_datetime" name="datetime" type="text" required/>
</div>
<script>(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#id_datetime").datetimepicker();
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

### Passing options to `jQuery.datetimepicker`

You can add `jQuery.datetimepicker` options according to your needs.
[See XDSoft's documentation for a full list of options.](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

```py
datetime = forms.DateTimeField(
widget=DateTimePicker(options={
'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
'language': 'en-us',
}),
)
```

for customization, You can use [docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-datetimepicker/)

Comment: i will try . Thank you.

Comment: I was not able to save the reserved date on the model. But, anyway I overcome this by creating TimeInput class. I had to create an extra column in the model.

Comment: this answer helped you?